# How can I measure group correlations?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I am interested in finding out whether there is any correlation between the behavior (1 variable) of individuals that are segregated in several groups of 3 or 5. This would be akin to a 3-way or 5-way correlation, I guess.

Is there a standard way to calculate such type of association?

Comment: Aren't you just comparing behavior to one factor (whether the group size is three or five)?

Comment: I want to see if, for instance, people in the same group have similar performances (say words per minute in a writing test), or if they are independent. Does it make sense?